# How to remove trailing newline from command arguments in fish?

Tags: fish

As far as I know, in `fish` as well as in many other command lines, the return statement is reserved for success/failure codes, and the standard way to 'return a string' is to `echo` the result like this:

```
function format-commit-message
    echo e2e-new: $argv[1]
    echo
    echo "Jira: APP-1234"
end
```

However, this means that all such strings end with a newline character. I tried to remove it because that is the commit message policy:

```
git commit -m ( format-commit-message "new commit" | string split0 | strig sub -e -1 )
```

But the result is:

> fatal: empty string is not a valid pathspec. please use . instead if you meant to match all paths

Could you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You might want to look at [`string trim`](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/string.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `echo`'s `-n` parameter to omit the newline.